# Como puedo generar una expresion regular para este caso?

Tags: javascript, regex

Tengo el problema de que cuando la geolocalizacion de google me trae la informacion de las coordenadas, en la parte de la localidad me devuelve el nombre de la misma antecedida por su código postal, de esta manera "E3100 Paraná". Lo que necesitaria es sacarle el código postal y dejar solo el nombre de la localidad. Probé de esta forma, pero no me da resultado:

```js
var localidad = "E3100 Paraná";
var patron = new RegExp('/E\d{*}');
if (patron.test(localidad)) {
  var recortada = localidad.split(patron);
  document.body.innerHTML = recortada[1];
} else {
  document.body.innerHTML = 'La localidad esta sin codigo postal';
}
```

Comment: Prueba con `'^E\\d+'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pruebe esto

```js
var localidad = "E3100 Paraná";
const regex = /^(E\d+\s)/;

var localidadSinCodPostal = localidad.replace(regex, '');

console.log(localidadSinCodPostal)

var localidadUruguay = "E3260 Concepción del Uruguay";

var localidadUruguaySinCodPostal = localidadUruguay.replace(regex, '');

console.log(localidadUruguaySinCodPostal)

var localidadNormal = "Concepción del Uruguay";

var localidadNormalSinCodPostal = localidadUruguay.replace(regex, '');

console.log(localidadNormalSinCodPostal )
```

con esto lo que se hace es eliminar del nombre si aparece la expresión del código postal, Saludos.

Brayan tiene razón por eso edito mi respuesta, con la expresión regular que le pongo donde uso `\d+`, lo que quiere decir es que al menos tenga un dígito, si usara `\d*` lo que quiere decir es que la cantidad de dígitos puede ser 0, y si usara `\d{n}` puede limitar la cantidad de dígitos que se espera por ejemplo `\d{4}` tiene que tener 4 dígitos

Comment: Tu respuesta puede mejorar si explicas la razón de por qué `\d{*}` y `\d+`, quizá el usuario busque una cantidad de dígitos del 0 a n y con `\d+` no, pero con `\d*` se puede. Más que nada explicar que significa `\d{K}` donde `K` siempre es un entero

Comment: Si, es que no hay mucho para explicar. O aparece el nombre de la localidad solamente, o apareceantecediéndolo a veces, el codigo Postal (que tiene el formato que ya vieron). Es el resultado de una acción que se genera utilizando la API de geolocalización de Google.

Comment: pero bueno si siempre tiene ese formato con esa lógica incluso si se asegura q siempre sean 4 números puede cambiar `\d+` por `\d{4}`, pero con esa lógica puede limpiar el código postal y quedarse con el nombre y en caso de que no venga el nombre no pasa nada raro simplemente se queda con el nombre igual puede comprobar el código que le comparto

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar :

```
var localidad = "E3100 Paraná";
var sLocalidad = localidad.split(" ");
if(sLocalidad.length == 2){
    console.log(sLocalidad[1]);
}else{
    console.log(sLocalidad[0]);
}
```

Asi usas el metodo split para dividir el string en 2 partes , [0] con el codigo postal y [1] con la localidad , espero que te funcione.

Comment: El caso es que no siempre aparece en ese formato... Muchas veces aparece correctamente solo la localidad, por lo cual tengo que comprobar la existencia de esos caracteres para proceder a recortar la cadena, o dejarla como está.

Comment: La eh remplazado para que se adapte a lo que dices. Espero que asi te funcione , esto solo sera posible si siempre llega la informacion con ese formato que declaraste , sino deberias eliminar de el array creado con el metodo split los strings que contengan numeros . Espero que te sirva esto

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por responder a mi pregunta, pero el tema es asi: El usuario mueve un puntero en el mapa y al soltarlo, trae ciertos datos, que yo separo con SPLIT para colocarlos en distintos campos. El nombre de la localidad que me devuelve, no siempre trae consigo el código postal, y no siempre tiene 1 sola palabra. A veces es "E3107 San Benito", "E3260 Concepción del Uruguay", "Villa Elisa", etc. Es por eso que necesito si o si matchear la existencia del código postal.